# Difficulty in understanding independent clause

Tags: clauses

In case of an independent clause, I am having difficulty in understanding a sentence. About clauses what I know is:
Definition: They are groups of words that contain a subject and a verb or they are used to add more detail to the noun in a sentence.
Example: The fast, red squirrel darted up a tree.
The subject, noun of this clause is the fast, red squirrel, and the verb is 'darted'.

Now, back to independent clauses.
An independent clause is a clause that can stand on its own as a distinct sentence. Example: "I love eating cookies."

The sentences I am having trouble with is this one: "His truck is green."

Here, the truck is the subject or noun. But there is no verb. Shouldn’t we say that this is not a clause?

Comment: In "His truck **is** green", the verb is "is". An independent clause is defined as one that is not dependent on another element in the sentence.

Comment: In "His truck **is** green", the verb is "is". An independent (main) clause is defined as one that is not dependent on another element in the sentence. Your example contains a finite verb and it is not embedded within a larger clause, so it qualifies as an independent (main) clause.

Comment: I think you are confusing 'subject' and 'referent referred to by subject'. 'Subject' is defined by how a string of words functions in a sentence. So '[John / He / A cat / The tree / The man from down the road who we see nearly every Thursday ...] [is] [clearly visible]'. The subject may be one word or many. The subject's _referent_ is variously _the well-loved (?) John, whoever 'he' refers to, some unidentified moggy, the obvious tree, Joe (from down the road, who goes by weekly ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His truck is green. In this sentence, ***is*** is the verb.

Be verb = am, is, are, was, were

An/is/are/was/were can be used as an auxiliary verb.

Am/is/are/was/were can also be used as a main verb.

Here ***is*** works as the main verb.

Comment: I am somehow unable to access the answer as there is no option for it. But your answers is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: *Accept the answer.

Comment: Which country r u from btw ?